# How to get rid of the 100 properties per account cap on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I'm working with Google Analytics and have reached the 100-properties-per-GoogleAccount-cap almost three times now. I was wondering if any of you guys know a way to remove the cap, or know of a system that makes these things easies.

Would be much obliged!

Comment: While you can create only 100 accounts AFAIK you can be invited to as many as you like. So create with a throwaway address, then add your proper address. At least that is how it used to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the cap increased many times, and it costs about $150k. :) Humour aside, you need to have a 360 (Premium) license, which helps greatly in increasing the limit. That's really the only way. But you might also want to ask yourself, why do you need so many to begin with? I can understand if you are a larger organisation (and hence can afford the 360 price tag) with a large GA account structure, but are you? If not, then you might need to consider reorganising your account. For example, use your views if you are tracking multiple subdomains or whatever. That's probably the best (and only) way for you.